# Effect of several downvotes on an answer

Tags: discussion

When an answer receives net 3 downvotes it gets kind of greyed out but I can still click it and interact with it.

Is this just a helpful visual prompt that the answer is minus scoring?

Are there any other effects at -3 and are there any other effects when it achieves any other minus score milestones?

I’m wondering what best to do, add another downvote, flag, comment, edit etc. And it might depend on being informed more in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed - its purely a visual indicator this is a low-ranked answer.

Looks like questions cannot turn grey, based on 
[What is the most downvoted post on stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/)

We've had low-ranked answers be "accepted" despite being low-ranked, the colour change shows its not highly regarded.

Best example I can find is https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/49906/19705 which is +4 and -5 for a nett score of -1, not enough to go grey yet.

Comment: Lowest question score (that is not closed as dupe or on hold) is currently https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54282/ with -8

Comment: Harder to find low-scoring answers - the lowest I found was https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37019/19705 at -5 but there's very likely lower.

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16253/why-arent-average-speeds-computed-over-distance/40672#40672 is our lowest-scoring answer (and happens to be accepted).